# How to make a button selected/highlighted by default

Tags: jquery, html

I was using my own confirm box with the help of kendo window. I displayed two buttons in it and everything is fine. But here comes issue, I want to make any of the button selected by default, so an user can navigate between the buttons.

Note: I don't want to use plugin.
                              Thanks in Advance
Regards 
Varun

Comment: `$(element).focus()` in **jQuery**

Comment: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689409/how-to-make-a-button-selected-highlighted-by-default?noredirect=1#comment24017927_16689409) _ Focus worked, Thanks for your help Rohit_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach, given the following HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <button id="button1">Button one</button>
    <button id="button2">Button two</button>
</form>
```

Would be:

```
var buttons = $('form').find('button');

buttons.eq(Math.floor(
    Math.random() * buttons.length
)).focus();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GAzjm/).

References:

- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
  - [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
- jQuery:

  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Comment: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689409/how-to-make-a-button-selected-highlighted-by-default?noredirect=1#comment24017927_16689409)_This works absolutely fine, thanks for that. How about navigate between buttons using keyboard._

Comment: You're very welcome; I'm glad to have been of help. As to the other, that would be a separate question, I think.